# Neo4J CYPHER in C# or Java: Return JSON output from “call db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()”?

Tags: java, c#, json, neo4j, cypher

When calling `db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()` from within the Neo4J Broswer, the Code side tab returns the complete JSON schema in the Response drop-down. Is it possible to retrieve this JSON result in C# or Java using the Neo4J.Driver? I would like to deserialize the JSON text into C# classes.

[Screen-cap of Response drop-down from db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI5yl.png)

I have explored the Neo4J.Driver `IDriver`, `IAsyncSession` and `IResultCursor` calls and cannot find a way to retrieve the JSON dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I wanted by using `apoc.export.json.all` to stream in a JSON dataset of the entire database. I leveraged the examples at https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/export/json/#export-database-json. I apologize for what turned out to be the misdirection of my question. `db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()` was not going to get me what I really needed.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public async void TestNeo4j()
{
    // Set up the graph database driver and connect the session to the Neo4J database.
    IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(Neo4JBoltURI, AuthTokens.Basic(Neo4JUser, Neo4JPassword));
    IAsyncSession session = driver.AsyncSession();
    IResultCursor cursor;

    try
    {
        // Bring the JSON text in as a stream
        string query = "CALL apoc.export.json.all(null,{stream:true,useTypes:true}) " +
            "YIELD file, nodes, relationships, properties, data " +
            "RETURN file, nodes, relationships, properties, data";

        cursor = await session.RunAsync(query);
        string sJsonData = await cursor.SingleAsync(record => record["data"].As<string>());
        //Debug.Log(sJsonData);

        //// Save the JSON to a file.
        //string path = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Neo4JExportAll.json";
        //if (File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
        //File.WriteAllText(path, sJsonData);

        // Each line is a separate JSON statement describing a node or a relationship
        // Iterate all statements
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(sJsonData))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    // Deserialize the JSON line into JObject jo.
                    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(line);
                    // Dig into the JObject to get the data from the stream.
                }

            } while (line != null);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await session.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```