# Exporting whole neo4j database in .NET using BoltGraphClient

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Can anyone tell me how to export an entire neo4j database (so including properties, relationships, paths) to e.g. JSON or CSV using c# and in particular by using the BoltGraphClient connection method. I can of course do it within neo4j simply by clicking the export button but I want to do it using .NET and then just stream the JSON to a local file.
I'm feeling a bit limited by the query methods found with BoltGraphClient, figured it would be easier just to manipulate a JSON file.
Thanks in advance!

I've tried adapting the answer given to this question (it's achieved using GraphDatabase.Driver, rather than BoltGraphClient).
[Neo4J CYPHER in C# or Java: Return JSON output from “call db.schema.nodeTypeProperties()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687370/neo4j-cypher-in-c-sharp-or-java-return-json-output-from-call-db-schema-nodetyp)

But no joy.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use 'MATCH(n) RETURN n 'query to get all stuff

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert the node and relationship-objects that come back from the bolt-client, you can construct the "Dict" also on the server.

You can probably just run these queries from the bolt client:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN {id:id(n), labels:labels(n), properties:properties(n)} as node


MATCH (r) RETURN {id:id(r), type:type(r), properties:properties(r), start:id(startNode(r)), end:id(endNode(r))} as rel
```

HTH